# Google geolocation address search returning same search exact result with partial_match = true

Tags: javascript, api, maps, google-geocoder

I'm calling the google places map API with the following request (with my google API key):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=32/36+Nagle+St,+Liverpool+NSW&components=postal_code:2170|country:AU&key={your key}

And it returns the following JSON:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "32",
               "short_name" : "32",
               "types" : [ "subpremise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "36",
               "short_name" : "36",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Nagle Street",
               "short_name" : "Nagle St",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Liverpool",
               "short_name" : "Liverpool",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Liverpool City Council",
               "short_name" : "Liverpool",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New South Wales",
               "short_name" : "NSW",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Australia",
               "short_name" : "AU",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "2170",
               "short_name" : "2170",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "32/36 Nagle St, Liverpool NSW 2170, Australia",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.92853530000001,
               "lng" : 150.9219302
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -33.92718631970851,
                  "lng" : 150.9232791802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -33.92988428029151,
                  "lng" : 150.9205812197085
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "Ei0zMi8zNiBOYWdsZSBTdCwgTGl2ZXJwb29sIE5TVyAyMTcwLCBBdXN0cmFsaWE",
         "types" : [ "subpremise" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Why does the result have partial_match = true here when the address passed in as the same resulting "partial match" address?

```
"partial_match" : true
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be happening because the result was interpolated, it is not a feature from Google database and the position was calculated based on the interpolation.

Have a look at the place ID in the response.

`Ei0zMi8zNiBOYWdsZSBTdCwgTGl2ZXJwb29sIE5TVyAyMTcwLCBBdXN0cmFsaWE`

Typically these long place IDs correspond to interpolations, the result was guessed and my assumption is that the API sets a partial match flag in such situation.

The features that can be found in the Google database typically have shorter place ID. E.g. `ChIJARdFFWLRhIARK6RIUxEbJ30`.

https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#id-overview